# Как скомпилировать все файлы в каталоге и подкаталогах через g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Как скомпилировать все файлы в каталоге и во всех подкаталогах?

Я знаю что можно скомпилировать все файлы в одном каталоге с помощью

`g++ *.cpp -o test`

но как рекурсивно пройтись по всем подкаталогам и скомпилировать все находящиеся в них файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По хорошему, Вам нужно воспользоваться любом системой сборки (Make, ninja) или системой подготовки файла сборки (bazel, CMake).

Но если очень-очень хочется, то можно написать так

```
gcc **/*.cpp -o test
```

правда иногда это не работает и нужно отдельно включать через `shopt -s globstar`

если что, всегда можно проверить через `ls **/*.cpp` что именно будет компилироваться.